Error while upgrading the Clojure project from Java 8 to Java 17
When I did upgrade my Clojure project to OpenJDK 17, I am facing unusual exceptions.
The get-object function of S3 expects two arguments which we were passing as map in format
(s3/get-object :bucket-name "bucketname" :key "filename.json")

but now this is getting treated as four arguments I guess.
You faked #'get-object with an argument count that doesn't match the function's defined arguments:
Provided 4 argument(s), where valid options are: 1, 2 arguments

14:15:53.243|E| #error {
:cause Cannot open  as a Reader.
:via
[{:type com.netflix.hystrix.exception.HystrixRuntimeException
:message s-clojure.component.s3-storage/s3-get-object-contents failed and no fallback available.
:at [com.netflix.hystrix.AbstractCommand$22 call AbstractCommand.java 822]}
{:type java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
:message Cannot open  as a Reader.
:at [clojure.java.io$fn__11641 invokeStatic io.clj 288]}]

Provided 4 argument(s), where valid options are: 1, 2 arguments
Another error that is occurring
|E| #error { :cause Cannot open <nil> as a Reader.  
:via  [{:type com.netflix.hystrix.exception.HystrixRuntimeException  
:message s-clojure.component.s3-storage/s3-get-object-contents failed and no fallback available.  
:at [com.netflix.hystrix.AbstractCommand$22 call AbstractCommand.java 822]}  {:type java.lang.IllegalArgumentException  
:message Cannot open <nil> as a Reader.  
:at [clojure.java.io$fn__11641 invokeStatic io.clj 288]}]  

Does this code work using java 17 in Clojure work?
{:input-stream (java.io.ByteArrayInputStream. (.getBytes response "UTF-8"))}


Java 17 has been superseded (https://jdk.java.net/17/) and using a newer version or version 11 is recommended.

By mentioning Java 17 is superseded but are you recommending to use lesser Java 11?

@Harold 17 is LTS, with planned support until at least 2026. Using the latest version is all well and good, but 17 is a very respectable version. Additionally, 17 is one of the versions Clojure plans to support long-term. Why do you recommend a downgrade to 11?

Are there any potential changes that has to be dealt with while upgrading to java 17? How can I find them considering the least community support for clojure. @Harold

I personally had many problems (some similar to the one reported in this question) when testing Java 17. We are using 11 in production right now. Hope that helps.

Looks like you've run into this issue: https://github.com/mcohen01/amazonica/issues/323
Amazonica is built on the Amazon v1 SDK which doesn't support JDK 17.
You'll either need to stay on JDK 11 until Amazonica moves to the v2 SDK or switch to something like https://github.com/cognitect-labs/aws-api (although bear this issue in mind for the latter: https://github.com/cognitect-labs/aws-api/issues/250 )

Is the issue with amazonica and aws sdk v1 for certain specific aws services because we do have another microservice which we migrated to java 17 without any hassle?

No idea, I don't use Amazonica, I'm just basing my answer on what's in the backlog of issues on that repo. At work we use the aws-api library instead (with JDK 21).
